Changing the output directory of the generated file by the injectable flutter package
I used the injectable package to generate the DI code for Get_It
Now injectable generates a main.config.dart file from the main.dart after applying @InjectableInit to the dependences function.
buid.yaml
 injectable_generator:injectable_config_builder:
        options:
          build_extensions:
            '^{{dir}}/{{file}}.dart': '{{dir}}/.generated/{{file}}.config.dart'
        enabled: true

main.dart
import '.generated/main.config.dart';

final getIt = GetIt.instance;

@InjectableInit(
  initializerName: r'$initGetIt',
  preferRelativeImports: true,
  asExtension: false,
)
void dependencies() => $initGetIt(getIt);

void main() {
  dependencies();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

I was expecting the main.config.dart file to be generated in .generated/main.config.dart
